# AngularJS - Get Authenticated User Data

Tags: angularjs, laravel, jwt, restangular, satellizer

I'm trying to get the authenticated user data so I can display the name of the user. I'm using AngularJS and Laravel.

When I do:

```
public function getUser(){

  if(Auth::check()){

    $user = Auth::user();
    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
    dd($user);
    return response()->success(compact('user','token'));

  }

}
```

The Auth is null, but I'm logged in.

This is my login method

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->error('Invalid credentials', 401);
        }
    } catch (\JWTException $e) {
        return response()->error('Could not create token', 500);
    }

    $user = Auth::user();

    return response()->success(compact('user', 'token'));
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try this? `Auth::user()->id` what does it print?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Where is the `getUser()` function defined? do you have `use Auth;` on top?

Comment: In AuthController and yes Auth is on top.